# Component styles in angular 1.5?

Tags: angularjs, webpack, components

Is there any way to get component styles in Angular 1.5?

In particular, I want the following:

- auto-generated classes for uniqueness
- styles not affecting child or parent components

I've got webpack and es6 setup, but I haven't found a way to use component styles yet.

Comment: You can use component names in css, not classes. They wont affect parents, but of course they wil affect childs. Dont think you may do something with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try css-modules, it's pretty easy to do it with webpack (css-loader) and angular

[css modules and angular 1.5](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules/blob/master/docs/css-modules-with-angular.md#css-modules-with-angular-15-component)

[webpack integration](https://github.com/css-modules/webpack-demo#css-modules-webpack-demo)

Comment: That looks like what I want, kind of, but the documentation doesn't inspire confidence in the tool.

Comment: look at this [repo](https://github.com/nlarche/css-modules-angular-1), this is a complete example with angular 1.5, webpack and css modules :